# Windows pgpass.conf file does not work with PHP's shell_exec()

Tags: php, windows, postgresql, passwords

I have a windows/apache/php/postgres installed (php 5.3 and Postgres 9)
I'm trying to execute a "psql" command line from PHP, so for this I need psql doesn't ask for the password.
I already have a pgpass.conf file in the `%appdata%/postgresql` path

If I execute the line from the windows command line

```
"C:\Program Files\BitNami WAPPStack\postgresql\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -w -d [DB] < "[SQL FILE]"
```

it works fine, but when is done through PHP with shell_exec() it does not work, apache error log says `"psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"`

So, I don't know why it works from command line but not from PHP's `shell_exec()`

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

`%appdata%` is probably not the same between apache's execution environment and the windows command line you're testing against. Generally on Windows, apache is expected to run as a service under the `LocalSystem` account (see [Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html))

But you could store a `pgpass.conf` file at a different place pointed to by the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable in apache (a `SetEnv` declaration in apache configuration file should do, or in the php code).

Or avoid the password file altogether and set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable directly to the value of the password just before executing `psql`.

Comment: Since i was doing this for a local connection to postgres, I just changed the pg_hba.conf file so the local connections were now TRUST. So I no longer use the pgpass file.